# Random No.s algorithm

Tags: algorithm, random, numbers, pseudocode

Level: Newbie
q1)Do true random number exists?
q2)If I were to reverse engineer a series of no.s would be random any longer?
q3)Is AP, GP (Arithmetic Prog, Geometric prog) a random series?
q4)Is there any formula for random number generation?
q5)Can anyone write an algorithm for true random no.s?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. This will not only make it easier to answer. It will also help others who search for siimilar answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article. I think it has answers to many of your questions.

http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/can-computer-generate-truly-random-number